# How to connect to PostgreSQL from postman script for automated api test

Tags: postgresql, postman

I am trying to find  a way to connect DB from postman and how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot connect postman to an external api :

Postman allows only the below list of nodejs libraries in the test script and pre request section:

https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#using-external-libraries

you can use native js libraries if it has a cdn equalent please see the discussion here:

https://community.postman.com/t/adding-external-libraries-to-postman/1971/8

So to answer your question , the best way will be to write a nodejs program to conect to postgresSQL and expose it by wrapping it with express API . SO that postman can access the result.

ALso see if the below example collection helps:

https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/5922408/RznJmGfn#ed6af38c-dd01-4a9c-9e40-d1071276d6a0

Answer (score 0):

Connect Postman to Postgres
Use a tool like https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest to set up a REST API.